# Verbs that can have the subject right after them

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

I saw this phrase: "to look the horse in the mouth" and remembered that there are many more such phrases out there.

What are such constructions called and how do they function?

Comment: Your cited phrase can be the subject of a sentence.

Comment: I really don't understand this question.    Are you asking why **look** there is like the transitive verb **punch** when it normally takes a prepositional phrase, as in **look at him**?

Comment: Don't you mean "verbs with the **object** right after them"?

Comment: @Laurel Why object? Isn't "the mouth" the object?

Comment: **mouth** is the object of the preposition but is not the object of **look**.  Someone can **look you in the eye**.

Comment: @SovereignSun "the horse" is the object of "look" and "in the mouth" is an adverbial construction. I'm not 100% sure how this works but I do think it's an exception due to the idiom. However, perhaps a comparison can be made with phrasal verbs like "look him over", "look/stare them down", "look it up"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Never look a gift horse in the mouth

This is a common English aphorism that means, "Don't be too critical about gifts you receive".  It's phrased as an [*imperative*](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/what-are-imperatives), so it's like a strong suggestion or command.

Many aphorisms are similarly phrased as imperatives:

> Look before you leap.  (Take reasonable precautions before you do anything risky)
>
> Don't count your chickens before they hatch.  (Don't assume an outcome before it actually happens)
>
> If it ain't broke, don't fix it
>
> When in Rome, do as the Romans do. (when in a different country or environment, act according to the customs and habits of that culture)
>
> Don't judge a book by its cover. (don't assume superficial appearance tells you everything about something)

and various others.  However you can phrase almost any statement as an imperative, if you want to use it as a request, command, or demand:

> Look both ways before crossing the street!
>
> Finish your vegetables, then you can have dessert!

and so on.

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question and is surprisingly mistargeted considering the level that SovereignSun has generally displayed around the site...

Comment: @LukeSawczak  OK, seems my answer is off-base.  Does SovereignSun mean the *object* not the *subject*?  I'm not sure why this would be unusual, e.g. **"Meet me there"** has a direct and an indirect object.  It's pretty common grammar.

Comment: I think he does mean the object — and specifically the absent of the phrasal element of "look *at*".